# Launch daemon not running on boot

Tags: mojave, osx-server, launchd

I've been following the [migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf) for macOS Server and have gotten stuck with the launch .plist for the BIND (named) DNS server. If I name the file the recommended `org.isc.named.plist` the service will not start on boot, but will run correctly when loaded with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist`. If I rename the file and `Label` property to anything else it will run correctly on boot.

I have checked if the service is disabled with `launchctl print-disabled system` and it is not shown.

I have tried on a fresh install of Mojave with only macOS Server installed and was also unsuccessful getting it to run at boot.

Comment: You should include the contents of the plist.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried the suggested answer but am having no luck. To be specific I first added the Program key entry which is in the “answer” but not in the Apple migration text (just ProgramArguments there). I then removed the -f option to match the plist in the answer. Again no change in behavior: runs after a manual sudo launchctl load ... command but after reboot it doesn’t automatically reload. Did you ever manage to resolve this issue for yourself?

Comment: @farf I eventually reinstalled the OS which fixed it as a DNS server was the first thing I tried to set up. I suspect a disabled state was saved/cached in some file, but I was never able to find what file it was.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-f` option, it's works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
       <plist version="1.0">
            <dict>
               <key>Disabled</key>
               <true/>
               <key>EnableTransactions</key>
               <true/>
               <key>Label</key>
               <string>org.isc.named</string>
               <key>KeepAlive</key>
               <true/>
               <key>ProcessType</key>
               <string>Standard</string>
               <key>Program</key>
               <string>/usr/local/sbin/named</string>
               <key>ProgramArguments</key>
               <array>
               <string>/usr/local/sbin/named</string>
               <string>-c</string>
               <string>/Library/Server/named/named.conf</string>
               </array>
            </dict>
       </plist>
```